# How to pass and access data between routes in angular?

Tags: angular

How to pass and access data between routes in angular?

Can some one suggest how can I access this optional object `{ foo: 'foo' }` inside the target routed component?

```
<a [routerLink]="['/profile/1', { foo: 'foo' }]">Profile</a>
```

Comment: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-data-to-route/

Comment: What about the above one?? I'm not talking about state or data. Here in the above example we are passing an optional object. How can I access this from the target component. I've taken this directly from angular docs. But details on how to access it is not written there.

Comment: "_What about the above one??_" - what about it? Are you expecting an answer like "Yes, you can use that approach" or "No, you shouldn't use that"?

Comment: Yes . How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActivatedRoute` to access that object.

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.data.subscribe(v => {
    // v should contain the parameters passed
    console.log(v)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data)
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `state`

```
<a [routerLink]="['/profile/1']" [state]="{ foo: 'foo' }">Profile</a>
```

and in the component you can do the following:

```
constructor(private router: Router){
  router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart)).subscribe(e => { 
  console.log(router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.foo);
 });
}
```